# How do you write to a span using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to populate a `<span></span>` element on the page load with jQuery.

At the moment the value that gets populated into the span is just an integer count.

Here I have named my span *userCount*:

```
<a href="#" class="">Users<span id = "userCount"></span></a>
```

I am trying to write the value of the span with no success.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post("Dashboard/UsersGet", {}, function (dataset) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(dataSet);
        var table = obj.Table;

        var countUsers;
        for (var i = 0, len = table.length; i < len; i++) {
            var array = table[i];
            if (array.Active == 1) {
                  var name = array.Name;
            }
            countUsers = i;
        }
        userCount.innerHTML = countUsers.toString();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you do `var name = array.Name;` ? Is some code missing ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have any `usercount` variable. Use `$(selector)` to build a jquery object on which you can call functions like [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
 $('#userCount').html(countUsers);
```

Note also that

- you don't need to convert your integer to a string manually.
- if you don't break from the loop, `countUsers` will always be `table.length-1`.
- you have a typo : `dataSet` instead of `dataset`. Javascript is case sensitive.
- you don't need to parse the result of the request
- you don't need to pass empty data : `jQuery.post` checks the type of the provided parameters

So, this is probably more what you need, supposing you do other things in the loop :

```
    $.post("Dashboard/UsersGet", function (dataset) {
        var table = dataset.Table;
        var countUsers = table.length; // -1 ?
        // for now, the following loop is useless
        for (var i=0, i<table.length; i++) { // really no need to optimize away the table.length
            var array = table[i];
            if (array.Active == 1) { // I hope array isn't an array...
                var name = array.Name; // why ? This serves to nothing
            }
        }
        $('#userCount').html(countUsers);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)!

```
<a href="#" class="">Users<span id = "userCount"></span></a>
```

Since you have assigned an `id` to the `span`, you can easily populate the `span` with the help of `id` and the function [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
$("#userCount").html(5000);
```

Or in your case:

```
$("#userCount").html(countUsers.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
userCount.innerHTML = countUsers.toString();
```

to:

```
$("#userCount").html(countUsers.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
userCount.innerHTML = countUsers.toString();
```

use:

```
$('#userCount').html(countUsers.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('#userCount').text(countUsers);
```

to write data to span

Answer (score 0):

The call back argument should be `dataSet` rather than `dataset`?